# Adding a single row at the end of `ArrayList`

Tags: java, arraylist

folks, how can I add an additional row to the end of the  `2D ArrayList`? What is the technique for that? Or how should I approach it? I haven't written a code for that because I don't how to start it.

I have a `2D ArrayList` which is

`ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> myBoard = new ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>();`
and would like to add an additional line to its end but do not know how to approach it. My `2D ArrayList` looks like the following:

```
The number of rows is 6
The number of cols is 3
ABC
AAA
BAC
BEC
BEA
BAB
```

Could please smb help me?

```
public void addRowBottom(ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> myBoard){
      ArrayList<T> addRow = new ArrayList<T>();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List is ordered Collection. When you add to the list it already adds at end. That will the highest indexed element in the list.

```
public void addRowBottom(ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> myBoard){
      ArrayList<T> addRow = new ArrayList<T>();
      //add data to addRow
      myBoard.add(addRow);
}
```

Comment: @Michael Yes. Try and see ;)

Comment: @SureshAtta, thanks for the response! One more question: to add a column in the end, should I run a loop through the `myBoard` and add an empty space in the end of each line? I'd appreciate it!

Comment: @Michael You should ask that as a new question. Anyways, what do you mean by `empty space in the end of each line` ?

Comment: @SureshAtta, I will ask it as a new question soon if I do not figure out it on my own. Thank you!